# Mage2: configurable product on one "store", but simple products on a different store?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, products

So we are implementing Magento as a replacement to what we have now. The exciting part is that we can keep multiple different "stores" or front end interfaces with a single backend. So we have our Consumer customers and products and then we have similar products but we have our Wholesale customers.

It seems to me that each product can be set to display on certain stores, as well as categories and the like. In fact there are tons of settings to differentiate functionality between stores.

But in my example I have one product that has 3 scents and comes in 4 sizes, so I've created that as a configurable product, which of course is made up of Simple products, one for each combination of options. For our consumers we want to display this as just one item with options, it keeps it simple and allows them to find it and make a selection.

However, on our wholesale store, our customers like to just go down the page and click and buy each item that they want. So it seems based on this use, it would work best to display 12 products instead of 1 product with 12 product option combinations.

Is this possible? It seems to me that I can control what is being displayed on either store, but there is no control to define if an item is displayed in the catalog at the store level, it either is for all stores or it isn't.

If it is possible I'd love to have someone at least point me in the right direction. I can't seem to put together a qualified search to get the results I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the product settings you will find an attribute "visibility" which you can configure **per store view**.

[image: screenshot]

#### For the consumers store, set it up like this:

- Configurable products: Catalog, Search
- Simple products: Not visible individually

#### For the wholesale store:

- Configurable products: Not visible individually (or better, disable them entirely for the wholesale store)
- Simple products: Catalog, Search

Comment: Well you can't set this per store view it seems. But at the same time I cannot find anything called an "Advanced Product Setting". There is a section called "Product in websites" where I can define which website it displays for each product. And then under "Autosettings" I can define visibility which affect all stores or any store that it belongs to. So how can I set this per store view?

Comment: You can, but my mistake, it's not in an "advanced" section, see my screenshot (this is Magento 2.1)

Comment: Ah excellent, I keep missing the fact that I can change the Store View at the top. Thanks for the help. That works perfectly. I gave you an up vote but I'm still a newbie with only a 6 reputation so it's not visible.